# spring mybatis get last insert id with @Transactional

Tags: spring, transactions, mybatis

I have two tables: User and SocialAccount. One user can have many socialAccount.

I have to create a user before create a socialAccount:

```
@Transactional
public SocialAccount create(SocialAccount socialAccount) {
    if (socialAccount.getUserId() == null) {
        User user = new User();
        userDao.createUser(user);
        System.out.println(user.getId());

        if(user.getId() == null){
            return null;
        }

        socialAccount.setUserId(user.getId());
    }
    return socialAccountDao.create(socialAccount);
}
```

In this method, firstly i create a user, but with @Transactional I get user.getId() is null. when I delete @Transactional the user.getId() is normal.

here is my spring config:

```
<bean name="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"></tx:annotation-driven>
```

and here is userDao.createUser() methods:

```
public User createUser(User user) {
    int affectedNum = super.getSqlSession().insert("UserSQL.createUser", user);
    if (affectedNum > 0) {
        return user;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and my mapper is:

```
<insert id="createUser" parameterType="User">
    <selectKey resultType="java.lang.Long" keyProperty="id" order="AFTER" >
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id
    </selectKey>
    INSERT INTO User(CTIME, UTIME) VALUES (now(), now())
</insert>
```

Can some people tell me how to get user id with @Transactional?

Comment: I don't think Transactional has anything to do with userid. If you remove transactional, do you still get that as null ?

Comment: @Shinchan，when i remove Transactional i can get userid which is not null

Answer (score 1):

try with below change in your mapper XML.

```
<insert id="createUser" parameterType="User">
    INSERT INTO User(CTIME, UTIME) VALUES (now(), now())
    <selectKey resultType="User" keyProperty="id" order="AFTER" >
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id
    </selectKey>        
</insert>
```

here in Selectkey tag keyProperty id will be your User POJO variable.